# CodeIgniter - Abrir PDF en otra pestaña

Tags: codeigniter

tengo una función en un controlador, la cual recibe la petición para descargar un archivo PDF. La cual recibe el identificador del fichero a descargar.

```
public function descargas($datos)
{
   ....
   $this->load->helper('download');
   $file="archivos/".$datos['file'];
   $data = file_get_contents(base_url() . $file);

   force_download($datos['file'], $data); 
}
```

Lo que necesito es que en vez de abrir el cuadro de dialogo para descargar el archivo, lo abra en otra pestaña del navegador.

Desde otro aplicativo tengo la siguiente llamada a la función

```
<a href="http://mipagina/descargas?file=mipdf.pdf&idioma=es" target="_blank">Descarga</a>
```

Según esta, me muestra el cuadro de dialogo para descargar/abrir el PFD en el equipo del peticionario.

Mi pregunta es:

¿Como puedo indicarle que me abra el PDF en una pestaña del navegador y no mostrar el cuadro de dialog0?

Saludos

Comment: Podrías intentar hacerlo con JavaScript, aunque en tu código no veo ningún problema

Comment: En mi código, según está ahora abre el modal para guardar el fichero con el "force_download". Y lo que quiero es poder poder abrir el fichero en una pestaña nueva

Comment: Y en tu helper lo que cargas es el archivo?

Comment: Si, carga las cabeceras y el fichero.

Comment: header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($data));

Comment: Este es el mime aplicados: 'application/pdf', 'application/x-download'